# AngularJS node mongodb auth issue using token auhenticaton

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm studying AngularJS Node and MongoDB, I got a great Video Tutorial from the Internet.  and as I'm getting to the late chapters, I've got stuck in one of the sample applications, that doesn't seem to work.

Error while Login

> Possibly unhandled rejection: {"message":"User have no token"}

My code is as follows.

CONTROLLER
mainController.js

```
angular.module('mainCtrl',[])
.controller('MainController',function($rootScope, $location, Auth){

    var vm = this;

    vm.loggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn();

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart',function(){
        vm.loggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn();

        Auth.getUser()
            .then(function(data){
                vm.user = data.data;
            })
            .catch(function (err) {});
        });

    vm.doLogin = function(){
        vm.processig = true;

        vm.err = '';

        Auth.login(vm.loginData.username,vm.loginData.password)
            .then(function(data){
                vm.processig = false;

                Auth.getUser()
                    .then(function(data){
                        vm.user = data.data;
                    });

                if(data.success)
                    $location.path('/');
                else
                    vm.error = data.message;
            });
    }


    vm.doLogout = function(){
        Auth.logout();
        $location.path('/logout');
    }

});
```

SERVICE
authServices.js

```
angular.module('authService',[])

.factory('Auth',function($http, $q, AuthToken){


    var authFactory = {};

    authFactory.login= function(username,password){
        return $http.post('/api/login',{
            username:username,
            password:password
        })
        .then(function(data){
            AuthToken.setToken(data.token);
            return data;
        });
    }

    authFactory.logout = function(){
        AuthToken.setToken();
    }

    authFactory.isLoggedIn = function(){
        if(AuthToken.getToken())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    authFactory.getUser = function(){
        if(AuthToken.getToken())
            return $http.get('/api/me/');
        else
            return $q.reject({message:"User have no token"});
    }
    return authFactory;
});




.factory('AuthToken', function($window){

    var authTokenFactory = {};

    authTokenFactory.getToken =  function(){
        return $window.localStorage.getItem('token');
    }

    authTokenFactory.setToken = function(token){
        if(token)
            $window.localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        else
            $window.localStorage.removeItem('token');
    }
    return authTokenFactory;
})



.factory('AuthInterceptor',function($q,$location,AuthToken){
    var interceptorFactory = {};

    interceptorFactory.request = function(config){
        var token = AuthToken.getToken();
        if(token){
            config.headers['x-access-token'] = token;
        }

        return config;
    };

    interceptorFactory.responseError = function(response){
        if(response.status == 403)
            $location.path('/login');

        return $q.reject(response);
    }

    return interceptorFactory;
});
```

what I'm missing..??

check my  [Projec Here](https://github.com/kannandevan/usersstory)

Comment: Did you check the localStorage in the browser? Is there a key-value of token exist? Based on the error, it seems that the 'key' names token is not present in the locastorage.

Comment: checked but there is no token

Comment: Yes, that is the reason. As there is no token in the localStorage and you are trying to read the token from localStorage, you are facing this issue. Add a dummy token manually and run. I believe it would be successful.

Comment: I tried to add a token there but no use
Please check this [My code here](https://github.com/kannandevan/usersstory)

Comment: @Sreehari Can u help me..??